# I am a member of a facebook group but members cannot tag me in a post

Tags: facebook

How can I fix that so I can be tagged in the post?

Answer (score 1):

Are you under 18? If so, you can only be tagged by friends or friends of friends.

According to Facebook Help Center's [Who can tag me?](https://www.facebook.com/help/226296694047060)

> Anyone can tag you in photos and other posts. Tags from people you're
>   not friends with may appear in your [timeline review](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/168229546579373) where you can
>   decide if you want to allow them on your timeline. Remember, posts you
>   choose not to allow on your timeline may appear in News Feed and
>   elsewhere on Facebook.
>
> If you don't like something you're tagged in, you can [remove the tag](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/140906109319589)
>   or [ask the person who tagged you to remove the post](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/196434507090362).
>
> **Note:** Minors can only be tagged by friends and friends of friends.